# What is the difference between the system group and netgroup?

Tags: linux

What is the difference between the system group and netgroup (at least on ubuntu)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"System groups" (often just "groups") contain users<sup>[1]</sup>, and are one of the basic security concepts in UNIX and many other operating systems. Each user belongs to a primary group and any number of secondary groups; a group, like a user, can be allowed to access or modify certain files and directories using the usual `chown`, `chmod`, `chgrp`, `setfacl` tools.

"Netgroups", on the other hand, are part of NIS/YP directory services system used only in Unix-like systems. A netgroup contains entries in the form `(hostname, user, nis-domain)` (with all three items optional), and can describe a user on any host, any user on a specific host, and such. Netgroups are not used with files directly, but only by NIS-aware programs: NFS exported filesystems, *sudo*, system login rights.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Other operating systems may allow more advanced configurations; e.g. Windows NT supports groups as group members.